# jQuery slideToggle with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slidetoggle

I am trying to use slideToggle to show sections of my site.  Within each section, I want to use the bootstrap grid system to layout the contents within the section.  The problem is that the slideToggle resets to have no height (which appears to be because of the presence of

```
{ float: left; }
```

for bootstrap col-* elements).

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rcs2tej0/. 
I have pasted the bootstrap col-* css into the fiddle along with some of my own at the bottom.  Section 1 is the default bootstrap css.  Section 2 removes the float, but it will now not correctly follow the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

Just adding `overflow:auto;` to `.section-body` in your **CSS** will solve your issue.

**Replaced Code:**

```
.section-body {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:auto; /* ADDED */
}
```

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/rcs2tej0/3/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

why not using **[collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)** from bootstrap ... check this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/82vgvx03/)

```
<body>
    <div class="panel-group" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="section1">
                 <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" 
                       data-toggle="collapse" href="#body1" 
                       aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="body1">
                       Section 1
                    </a>
                  </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="body1" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                 role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="section1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4'>Hello</div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4'>I</div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4'>Am</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="section2">
                 <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" 
                       data-toggle="collapse" href="#body2" 
                       aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="body2">
                       Section 2
                    </a>
                  </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="body2" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                 role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="section2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class='col-xs-4 no-float'>Kyle</div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4 no-float'>Who</div>
                    <div class='col-xs-4 no-float'>Are</div>
                    <div class='col-xs-12 no-float'>You?
                        <button id='add_word'>Add Word</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I was getting the same problem with responsiveness using panel collapse so I tried to create my own. My guess is the problem I was encountering is the same for both bootstraps panel collapse and my own section collapse.